# How do I make letter size page break in html and css with contenteditable div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div contenteditable>` element that I want to have 8.5in by 11in page breaks like in Google Docs.
Here is some of my code:

```
    <div id="txt" class="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

It is not deployed yet, but the link is [here](https://pincescpu987.github.io/xwrite/).

Answer (score 1):

Okay check the snippet

```js
 window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
   // check the classname first 'myElement'
   if (e.target.className === 'myElement') {
     // get current element where user typing
     let currentElement = e.target
     const allElement = document.querySelectorAll('.myElement');
     let allElementArray = [];
     allElement.forEach(el => allElementArray.push(el));
     const nextElementIndex = allElementArray.indexOf(currentElement) + 1
     const nextElement = allElementArray[nextElementIndex];

     // page height
     const pageHeight = 8.5 * 96; // 1 inch = 96 px

     // stop typing if a new page already created and it is crosing the height
     if (currentElement.offsetHeight >= pageHeight && nextElement && e.which === 13) {
       // it only prevent hitting "enter" key from keyboard.
       // make it more flexible. Because not if a user don't 
       // hit enter key from keyboad, but keep writing, it will cross the line
       // and it will increate the page or div height. 
       e.preventDefault()
     }
     if (currentElement.offsetHeight >= pageHeight && !nextElement) {
       // add new page
       currentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
         `<div class="myElement" contenteditable></div>`)

       // focus on new page
       const newElement = document.querySelectorAll('.myElement')[nextElementIndex];
       newElement.focus()
     }
   }
 })
```

```css
.myElement {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto
}

.myElement:focus {
  outline: 3px solid dodgerblue
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement" contenteditable>Start typing here</div>
```

Comment: I would like to know how to make a page break like in Google Docs or Microsoft Word (every 8.5in there should be a new ```div``` element)

Comment: Okay I got your point just now. Check the answer now. I hope you are searching for this.  in this snippet, after typing till 8.5inch, you can type in the same div / page. after crossing 8.5 inch, it will create a new page (div) and keep focus on that after its created.
. You can check it in jsFiddle also.
https://jsfiddle.net/habibulislam6862/gfw27u0p/2/